# Removing periodic noise from image using Fourier Transform

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, noise, noise-reduction

I try to remove periodic noise from image by using frequency domain techniques. Therefore, i want to use Butterworth filter.

Codes are following:

```
function main()

img = imread('A1.jpg');
Size = size(img);
red = img(:,:,1); 
green = img(:,:,2);
blue = img(:,:,3); 
redx = done(red,100);
greenx = done(green,100);
bluex = done(blue,100);

LAST = cat(3,redx,greenx,bluex);
showIm(LAST);
figure, imshow(LAST), title('new LAST channel');

end

function Resultx = done(Img,R)

Img = im2double(Img);
Size = size(Img);
Img = fft2(Img);
Img = fftshift(Img);
Result = createHandImg(R,Size, Img);
Result = ifft2(Result);
Result = real(Result);
Resultx = (abs(Result));

end

function Result=createHandImg(r,Size,FourrierImg)

[x,y]=meshgrid(-1*Size(2)/2:Size(2)/2 -1 ,-1 * Size(1)/2:Size(1)/2 - 1);
SqrtArray=1./(1+((x.^2+y.^2)/double(r)).^1);
Tresholded=(SqrtArray<r);
Result =  FourrierImg.* Tresholded ;

end
```

My problem is that this codes can not change the noisy image. In other words, noisy image and "cleaned" image are almost the same. Even if I change the threshold, for our example it is 100 , image is only black or the same with noisy image. Does this code have problem? Also I try to Gaussian filter and other filter, but result is always the same. You can also propose other solution (in freq. domain) to remove periodic noise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should provide input and output images so we don't have to run your code to see what is going on...

Comment: As @Piglet says, you must provide images, else we are just guessing.

Comment: soryy for absence of image: link is here [img] (http://2.1m.yt/08Wyocr.jpg)